# Qt: Different sized QLabels on one line

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui, qlabel

I'm trying to display different images in my widget. I put the images in QLabels, and resize those labels.

I want to display them next to each other, so I'm using `QHBoxLayout`. However, when they are displayed, the centers of the images are lined up, where I want the bottom of the images to line up.

This is my code so far:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(ui->tagcloud);
QHBoxLayout * l = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
ui->tagcloud->setWidget(widget);

l->addStretch();
for(int i=0;i<lijst.size();++i)
{

    QLabel *lab = new QLabel;

    QPixmap pic((lijst[i].imgPath).c_str());
    int sizeChange = 50 + (2*lijst[i].percent);

    lab->setFixedSize(QSize(sizeChange, sizeChange));
    lab->setPixmap(pic);
    lab->setScaledContents(true);

    l->addWidget(lab);
}

l->addStretch();
l->setSpacing(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set alignment in both QHBoxLayout and QLabel to position items as you want. Take a look at the [setAlignment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#setAlignment) function and the [alignment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#alignment-prop) property.

Comment: I did that. But it just places my labels to the bottom of the page
and there bottomline is still not the same.
l->setAlignment(QT::AlignBottom);

Comment: @user2961097 What about lab->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);

Comment: I found the answer:
it had to be:
l->setAlignment(lab, Qt::AlignBottom);

I'll give you the checkmark, for bringing me close to the answer. Thanks

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy That's why link answers are so bad. They have to be kept up to date (which AntonyG just did, thanks Antony!)